# How to group Adobe CS5 application tabs in one window (like the Windows version)?

Tags: macos, windows, adobe

On Windows (7) my Adobe products have all their tabs and tab groups in the same window.

On Mac (OS X Lion) my Adobe products have all their tabs and tab groups separated floated every which way.

Is there a way on the Mac to group all these tabs like on the Windows machine?

See the different windows flung about the desktop:

[image]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8161/7609559970_fd3592c9a7_b.jpg))</sub>

I am using Adobe CS5.

Apparently I am not the only one complaining about this:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2010/04/dreamweaver_cs5_help_now_avail.html

Comment: I guess you can't do that in Dreamweaver CS5. I'm partial to having everything in separate windows myself: I have a question around here frantically asking how to turn the Application Frame *off* in Photoshop CS6.

Comment: I have since scrapped adobe's bloatware for more specific task oriented products. Coda Sketch FTW

Answer (score 1):

I only have CS6, and, in that version, I'd make sure Window > Application Frame was checked. This moves everything (documents, palettes, etc.) into one window frame like the Windows version.

Comment: Cool, half way there. `Use Application Frame` works great in Fireworks. Any solution for Dreamweaver CS5+?

Comment: Apparently I am not the only one complaining about this:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2010/04/dreamweaver_cs5_help_now_avail.html - I think I may be upgrading my Coda and making the switch permanent.

Comment: I probably launched Dreamweaver CS6 once just to make sure the install worked. I use mainly Photoshop and Illustrator, and I only have Photoshop on my work computer; the rest are at home.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check "Application Frame" in Dreamweaver as well... At least you can in CS6, I don't have CS5 installed anywhere any more. But for a more in depth look into how to style dreamweaver's layouts check out [this help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7f82a.html) from Adobe, it's pretty straight forward.

You may also find that changing to one of the other preset work spaces suits you better. It should be something like Window >> Workspace layout. You can create your own custom layouts, but you'll probably find one that suits you from the myriad of presets.

Answer (score -1):

For CS5, go to the "Window" tabs and scroll down to and click on "Application Frame". Everything should group into a window.